# Head bobbing never stops

Tags: unity, c#

I have this code on my player that makes the camera sway whenever I move, but the camera just never stops bobbing and swaying even when I'm standing still.

Here is the code:

```cs
{
    [SerializeField] private bool _enable = true;

    [SerializeField, Range(0, 0.1f)] private float _amplitude = 0.015f;
    [SerializeField, Range(0, 30)] private float _frequency = 10.0f;

    [SerializeField] private Transform _camera = null;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cameraHolder = null;

    private float _toggleSpeed = 3.0f;
    private Vector3 _startPos;
    private Rigidbody _controller;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _startPos = _camera.localPosition;
    }

     void Update()
    {
        ResetPosition();

         if (!_enable) return;

        CheckMotion();
        _camera.LookAt(FocusTarget());
        PlayMotion(FootStepMotion());
        
    }

    private void PlayMotion(Vector3 motion)
    {
       _camera.localPosition += motion;
    }

    private void CheckMotion()
    {
        

        float speed = new Vector3(_controller.velocity.x, 0, _controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

        if (speed < _toggleSpeed) return;
    }

    private Vector3 FootStepMotion()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y += Mathf.Sin(Time.time * _frequency) * _amplitude;
        pos.x += Mathf.Cos(Time.time * _frequency / 2)* _amplitude * 2;
        return pos;
    }

    private void ResetPosition()
    {
        if (_camera.localPosition == _startPos) return;
        _camera.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_camera.localPosition, _startPos, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
    private Vector3 FocusTarget()
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + _cameraHolder.localPosition.y, transform.position.z);
        pos += _cameraHolder.forward * 15.0f;
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your CheckMotion function does nothing. It looks like you're trying to use it to abort Update early, but a "return" in one method just returns from that method itself, it does not force its calling method to *also* return.

Comment: I see. I suppose that means that i have to remove the CheckMotion function entirely?

Comment: Or you could return a true/false, and use that value to decide whether to continue into the motion code.

Comment: yeah that sounds about right. thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Want to write up an answer below if that solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) at it again, killin it with another [solution in the comments](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203819/head-bobbing-never-stops#comment371280_203819)

> Your CheckMotion function does nothing. It looks like you're trying to use it to abort Update early, but a "return" in one method just returns from that method itself, it does not force its calling method to also return.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included not just the tip from the comments, but also the code showing how you would *apply* that tip to reach a solution to the problem.

Comment: agreed, though I'm not OP ‍♂️